# Calculate relative abundance by row label in R? (vegan package?)

Tags: r, dataframe, vegan

I'm trying to calculate relative abundances based based on row labels or names (get relative abundance for each test in `df$path1`. So I'd like to calculate the relative abundance of counts from `test1`, and calculate relative abundance of counts from `test2` separately. The sum of the relative abundance numbers from `test1` would equal 1.

I'm currently using the `vegan` package, but open to other options.

Test dataset:

```
library(vegan)
df <- data.frame(x = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 
                 path1 = c("test1", "test1", "test2", "test2", "test3"),
                 value = c(40, 10, 34, 12, 20))
df$relabun <- decostand(df[3], 2, method = "total") #takes relative abundace of whole column
```

Ideal output for relative abundance based on `df$path1`, would look like this:

```
x path1 relabun_bypath1
a test1 0.8
b test1 0.2
c test2 0.74
d test2 0.26
e test3 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic split–apply–combine question. The most literal way in base R is to

- split the data.frame by group with `split`,
- apply a function with `*apply`, and
- combine with `do.call(rbind, ... )` or `unlist`.

so

```
unlist(lapply(split(df, df$path1), function(x){x$value / sum(x$value)}))
#    test11    test12    test21    test22     test3 
# 0.8000000 0.2000000 0.7391304 0.2608696 1.0000000
```

which we can assign to a new variable. However, base has a nice if oddly-named function called `ave` which can apply a function across groups for us:

```
ave(df$value, df$path1, FUN = function(x){x / sum(x)})
# [1] 0.8000000 0.2000000 0.7391304 0.2608696 1.0000000
```

which is a good deal more concise, and can likewise be assigned to a new variable.

If you prefer the Hadleyverse, `dplyr`'s grouping can make the process more readable:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(path1) %>% mutate(relAbundByPath = value / sum(value))
# Source: local data frame [5 x 4]
# Groups: path1 [3]
# 
#        x  path1 value relAbundByPath
#   (fctr) (fctr) (dbl)          (dbl)
# 1      a  test1    40      0.8000000
# 2      b  test1    10      0.2000000
# 3      c  test2    34      0.7391304
# 4      d  test2    12      0.2608696
# 5      e  test3    20      1.0000000
```

As you can see, it returns a new version of the data.frame, which we can use to overwrite the existing one or make a new copy.

Whichever route you choose, get comfortable with the logic, because you'll likely use it a lot. Better, learn all of them. And `tapply` and `mapply`/`Map`. And `data.table`...why not?

---

**Note:** You can also replace the `value / sum(value))` construct with the `prop.table` function if you like. It's more concise (e.g. `ave(df$value, df$path1, FUN = prop.table)`), but less obvious what it's doing, which is why I didn't use it here.